# how to run a file using command line in kali linux that is gzip compressed data

Tags: kali-linux

I have a file and upon running the command file file_name, I get this
flag2: gzip compressed data, was "flag.txt", last modified: Tue May 21 22:52:20 2019, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 33
I have tried gunzip, xxd filename, but nothing seems to work.
cat flag2 gives me this .Ώ�M̫�O,J��,��K�/-���,�L-���;�

Comment: The non-printable characters in the string Ώ�M̫�O,J��,��K�/-���,�L-���;� are the result of the ZIP process, which uses the expanded character set to compress the file. We won't be able to get any useful information from them because of the nature of file compression. For a better understanding of ZIP, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)

Answer (score 0):

You must extract the file and mark it as executable before you can run it. Try

```
gzip -d file.gz && chmod 777 flag.txt && ./flag.txt
```

where **file.gz** is the compressed file.

Comment: i ran this   gzip -d flag2 && chmod 777 flag.txt && ./flag.txt

Comment: and got this error gzip: flag2: unknown suffix -- ignored

Comment: There was a file before this and when I unrar that file. it gave me this file and I was trying to execute this file and kept getting errors.

Comment: What was the name of that file?

Comment: it was flag3 and then before that, I had to unzip flag4 to get flag3